# How can I block Java updates, network-wide?

Tags: java

Java is constantly prompting users to upgrade and, when they do, it tries to install all sorts of other things which we must uninstall. Lately it installs a backup program called Carbonite.

We’ve banned Java unless the user has a specific reason why they need it. Those people are getting upgrade prompts with “ride along” software.

How can we stop this?

- What site is it contacting to see if there’s an upgrade? It should be easy to block that at the firewall. (We did the same thing with RealPlayer.)
- Is there a registry entry or group policy that can stop it?

Comment: +1 because I feel your pain.  Managing Java on a network can be a right headache - I've come to the conclusion myself that it's primarily a developer's plaything and not really suitable for corporate desktop use.

Comment: > We’ve banned Java unless the user has a specific reason why they need it.

I know this post is old.  Hoping you still monitor this account.  I'm curious how this has worked for you.  We are considering blocking Java also.

Comment: This did work, although we don’t do it any more. The current Java updates seem less-obnoxious.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To disable the auto-update notification you should be able to set the dword value at **HKLM\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Update\Policy\EnableJavaUpdate** to **0** and **HKLM\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Update\Policy\NotifyInstall** to **0**.

Here is a fragment from on of my startup scripts.

```
Option Explicit

Dim oShell
Set oShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

DisableJavaUpdateNotification()

Function DisableJavaUpdateNotification
    Dim Key,Value
    Key="HKLM\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Update\Policy\EnableJavaUpdate"
    Value="0"
    oShell.RegWrite Key,Value,"REG_DWORD"
    Key="HKLM\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Update\Policy\NotifyInstall"
    Value="0"
    oShell.RegWrite Key,Value,"REG_DWORD"
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks Zoredache. I’m testing this now and will add it to our GPOs tonight.

Comment: Looking at that registry key I also found a key called `PostStatusUrl` set to `https://sjremetrics.java.com/b/ss//6` — is there any reason why I shouldn’t block `sjremetrics.java.com`?

Comment: Don't know about blocking sjremetrics.java.com, It might be worth trying, but I would probably try it in a testing environment first.